# R: plot in a grid layout over multiple pages

Tags: r, r-grid

I'd like to arrange a 3x3 grid layout over 3 pages of a PDF file. I'd like to plot in arbitrary grid locations across the three pages. I know how to arrange multiple subplots using some option like `layout=c(3,3)`. I can figure out how to arrange a 3x3 layout on a single plot using the grid package, and then decide to choose which plot to use. However, I can't figure out how to lay out a 3x3 grid over 3 pages, and then choose which grid to plot in.

I was hoping `grid.newpage()` would solve my problem, as in the following:

```
library(grid)
pdf(file="griddtest.pdf",paper="letter")
vp1 <- viewport(x = 0, y = 0.5, w = 0.5, h = 0.5, just = c("left", "bottom"), 
    name = "vp1")
vp2 <- viewport(x = 0, y = 0.5, w = 0.5, h = 0.5, just = c("left", "bottom"), 
    name = "vp2")
pushViewport(vp1)
grid.text("Some drawing in graphics region 1 on page 1",y = 0.8)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(vp2)
grid.text("Some drawing in graphics region 2 on page 2",y = 0.8)
dev.off()
```

but this just generates the second page (I'm guessing 'newpage' overwrites the oldpage, rather than making a new page).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot operate on graphics on previous page. You will probably just have to rethink the way you are plotting the things.

Comment: Your example works for me: I get both pages. (Tested in R2.12.0 and R2.11.1 under WinXP)

Comment: @Richie Argh! How frustrating...

Comment: @Vitoshka I'm not sure I'm operating on graphics on a previous page in the example... If I am can you tell me how? I think I draw something on page 1 (vp1) then make a new page, then draw something on the new page...

Comment: Well, I understood from "I can't figure out how to lay out a 3x3 grid over 3 pages, and then choose which grid to plot in." that you want to plot on previous page. Now I see you don't want that. Your example works perfectly for me. I get 2 pages as expected.

Comment: There is onefile argument in pdf. Try to set it explicitly.

Comment: @Vitoshka thanks! My brain and my programming seem to operate independently a lot of the time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nine panels, and specify 3 panels in your layout, e.g.,

```
xyplot(runif(9) ~ 1:9 | 1:9, layout = c(1,3))
```

then you get 3 graphs drawn.  For plotting into the GUI window the plots get overwritten, but if you are saving to PDF they appear on consecutive pages.

---

EDIT: To make the plots only take up one third of the page, adjust the height of the plot in the call to `pdf`.

```
pdf(..., height = 3)
# ...
dev.off()
```

By default, this draws each plot in the centre of each page.  By setting `pagecentre = FALSE`, the plots appear at the bottom of each page.  I haven't found an option in `pdf` to make them appear at the top.

To get better control over the positioning of the plots, first save them to eps (with the `postscript` function) or to png.

You can then use `sweave` to create a pdf formatted however you like, including those files.  Alternatively, create a document in the word processor of your choice and manually import the image files.

Comment: Can I control  the layout of these panels so they only appear in the top third of the page? This was my brief...

Comment: @Mike, if you use latex (sweave) you can position your floats wherever you want (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)

Comment: @VitoshKa this, were it up to me, is exactly what I'd do. My brief, though, is to use R. Thanks for the help!